# Datasift Facebook PHP Client

Tags: php, facebook

How do I filter facebook data avaialble in datasift using csdl with a unique id which identifies a user.

Reading docos,
facebook.author.hash_id seems to be unique per user.

My CSDL,

```
$CSDL = 'facebook.author.hash_id == "some_facebook.author.hash_id"';
```

The datasift client library returns the following error,

> "Uncaught exception 'DataSift_Exception_CompileFailed' with message
>   'The target facebook.author.hash_id does not exist' "

However I'm able to filter facebook messages using,

'facebook.author.type == "user"' 
Both filter tags above, are mentioned in the below post. 
[Ref http://dev.datasift.com/docs/data/dictionary ]

How do we filter facebook messages using the author (hash_id or other) ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to filter for individual Facebook users with Datasift. Facebook asked for all its data to be anonymized.

The output you get from Datasift is not a one for one reflection of what can be filtered on, take a look at the [data dictionary](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/resources/dictionary).

The hash_id is created by Datasift to obscure the user's real ID. However, the hash_id will always be the same for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2015 the Facebook search API was deprecated. If you are looking for Facebook topic data you can take a look at [Datasift PYLON](http://datasift.com/products/pylon-for-facebook-topic-data/).